# Processing upper triangular elements only with NumPy einsum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I'm using numpy einsum to calculate the dot products of an array of column vectors pts, of shape (3,N), with itself, resulting on a matrix dotps, of shape (N,N), with all the dot products. This is the code I use:

```
dotps = np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', pts, pts)
```

This works, but I only need the values above the main diagonal. ie. the upper triangular part of the result without the diagonal. Is it possible to compute only these values with einsum? or in any other way that is faster than using einsum to compute the whole matrix?

My pts array can be quite large so if I could calculate only the values I need that would double my computation speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can slice relevant columns and then use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
R,C = np.triu_indices(N,1)
out = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',pts[:,R],pts[:,C])
```

Sample run -

```
In [109]: N = 5
     ...: pts = np.random.rand(3,N)
     ...: dotps = np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', pts, pts)
     ...: 

In [110]: dotps
Out[110]: 
array([[ 0.26529103,  0.30626052,  0.18373867,  0.13602931,  0.51162729],
       [ 0.30626052,  0.56132272,  0.5938057 ,  0.28750708,  0.9876753 ],
       [ 0.18373867,  0.5938057 ,  0.84699103,  0.35788749,  1.04483158],
       [ 0.13602931,  0.28750708,  0.35788749,  0.18274288,  0.4612556 ],
       [ 0.51162729,  0.9876753 ,  1.04483158,  0.4612556 ,  1.82723949]])

In [111]: R,C = np.triu_indices(N,1)
     ...: out = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',pts[:,R],pts[:,C])
     ...: 

In [112]: out
Out[112]: 
array([ 0.30626052,  0.18373867,  0.13602931,  0.51162729,  0.5938057 ,
        0.28750708,  0.9876753 ,  0.35788749,  1.04483158,  0.4612556 ])
```

---

Optimizing further -

Let's time our approach and see if there's any scope for improvement performance-wise.

```
In [126]: N = 5000

In [127]: pts = np.random.rand(3,N)

In [128]: %timeit np.triu_indices(N,1)
1 loops, best of 3: 413 ms per loop

In [129]: R,C = np.triu_indices(N,1)

In [130]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->j',pts[:,R],pts[:,C])
1 loops, best of 3: 1.47 s per loop
```

Staying within the memory constraints, it doesn't look like we can do much about optimizing `np.einsum`. So, let's shift the focus to `np.triu_indices`.

For `N = 4`, we have :

```
In [131]: N = 4

In [132]: np.triu_indices(N,1)
Out[132]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]))
```

It seems to be creating a regular pattern, sort of like a shifting one though. This could be written with a cumulative sum that has shifts at those `3` and `5` positions. Thinking generically, we would end up coding it something like this -

```
def triu_indices_cumsum(N):

    # Length of R and C index arrays
    L = (N*(N-1))/2

    # Positions along the R and C arrays that indicate 
    # shifting to the next row of the full array
    shifts_idx = np.arange(2,N)[::-1].cumsum()

    # Initialize "shift" arrays for finally leading to R and C
    shifts1_arr = np.zeros(L,dtype=int)
    shifts2_arr = np.ones(L,dtype=int)

    # At shift positions along the shifts array set appropriate values, 
    # such that when cumulative summed would lead to desired R and C arrays.
    shifts1_arr[shifts_idx] = 1
    shifts2_arr[shifts_idx] = -np.arange(N-2)[::-1]

    # Finall cumsum to give R, C
    R_arr = shifts1_arr.cumsum()
    C_arr = shifts2_arr.cumsum()
    return R_arr, C_arr
```

Let's time it for various `N's`!

```
In [133]: N = 100

In [134]: %timeit np.triu_indices(N,1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 122 µs per loop

In [135]: %timeit triu_indices_cumsum(N)
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.7 µs per loop

In [136]: N = 1000

In [137]: %timeit np.triu_indices(N,1)
100 loops, best of 3: 17 ms per loop

In [138]: %timeit triu_indices_cumsum(N)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.3 ms per loop
```

Thus, it looks like for decent `N's`, the customized cumsum based `triu_indices` might be worth a look!

Comment: Thanks. I just realised I didn't express my question well. Please see edit. Basically, what I need are the values above the main diagonal. ie. the upper triangular part of the result without the diagonal.